# My code cant find a function in my module script Roblox

Tags: module, lua, roblox

I'm writing a 2D game engine in Roblox for fun, but I have run into an issue.
It seems my code cant find the function I'm referencing.

My output says:

> Players.SpookyDervish.PlayerGui.SpookyEngine.SpookyEngine:31: attempt to call a nil value

I have 3 module scripts and a main script.

Here is my explorer window:
[image: A screenshot of my explorer window]

The main script:

```lua
local gui = script.Parent

local spookyEngine = require(gui:WaitForChild("SpookyEngine"))

spookyEngine.Init()

spookyEngine:CreateObject("TestObject", Vector2.new(0, 0), Vector2.new(50, 50), "rbxassetid://183598555", Color3.fromRGB(85, 170, 255))

wait(2)

spookyEngine:Transform("test", Vector2.new(50, 50), Vector2.new(50, 50), 0)
```

My SpookyEngine module:

```lua
local object = require(script:WaitForChild("Object"))
local input = require(script:WaitForChild("Input"))

local gui = script.Parent

local spookyEngine = {}

function spookyEngine.Init()
    spookyEngine.screen = Instance.new("Frame", gui)
    spookyEngine.screen.Name = "Screen"
    spookyEngine.screen.Position = UDim2.new(0.5, 0, 0.5, 0)
    spookyEngine.screen.Size = UDim2.new(1.25, 0, 1.25, 0)
    spookyEngine.screen.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    spookyEngine.screen.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    spookyEngine.screen.BorderSizePixel = 0
    spookyEngine.screen.BorderColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    
    object.Init()
    spookyEngine.objects = object.objects
    
    game.StarterGui:SetCoreGuiEnabled(Enum.CoreGuiType.All, false)
    
    print("INFO: Initialized SpookyEngine!")
end

function spookyEngine:CreateObject(name, pos, size, sprite, colour)
    object.New(name, pos, size, sprite, colour)
end

function spookyEngine:Transform(object, pos, size, rotation)
    object:Transform(nil, nil, nil, nil)
end

return spookyEngine
```

My object module:

```lua
local spookyEngine = script.Parent
local gui = spookyEngine.Parent

local Object = {}
Object.__index = Object

function Object.Init()
    local Objects = Instance.new("Folder", gui.Screen)
    Objects.Name = "Objects"
    
    Object.objects = Objects
end

function Object.New(name, pos, size, sprite, colour)
    local newObject = {}
    setmetatable(newObject, Object)
    
    local position = UDim2.new(0.5, pos.X, 0.5, pos.Y)
    local objectSize = UDim2.new(0, size.X, 0, size.Y)
    
    local newObjectInstance = Instance.new("Frame", Object.objects)
    newObjectInstance.Name = name
    newObjectInstance.Position = position
    newObjectInstance.Size = objectSize
    newObjectInstance.BackgroundColor3 = colour
    newObjectInstance.AnchorPoint = Vector2.new(0.5, 0.5)
    newObjectInstance.BorderSizePixel = 0
    
    if sprite ~= nil then
        local objectSprite = Instance.new("ImageLabel", newObjectInstance)
        objectSprite.Size = UDim2.new(1, 0, 1, 0)
        objectSprite.Name = "Sprite"
        objectSprite.Image = sprite
        objectSprite.BackgroundTransparency = 1
        objectSprite.BackgroundColor3 = colour
        newObjectInstance.BackgroundTransparency = 1
    end
    
    newObject.Name = name
    newObject.Position = position
    newObject.Size = objectSize
    newObject.Sprite = sprite
    newObject.Colour = colour
    newObject.Instance = newObjectInstance
    
    return newObject
end

function Object:Transform(object, pos, size, rotation)
    object = tostring(object)   

    if Object.objects:FindFirstChild(object) then

    else
        warn("ERROR: Cant find object with name: '"..object.."'")
    end
end

return Object
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is pointing at this line :

```
function spookyEngine:Transform(object, pos, size, rotation)
    object:Transform(nil, nil, nil, nil)
end
```

which is called by...

```
spookyEngine:Transform("test", Vector2.new(50, 50), Vector2.new(50, 50), 0)
```

Because you have a function argument named `object`, it shadows the `object` local variable that you used to define your module. So the string that you pass in is what gets used. So you are effectively trying to execute

```
string.Transform("test", nil, nil, nil, nil)
```

The lua string library does not have a function called `Transform`, so when you try to index the function, it comes back as `nil`. That is why you get the error `attempt to call a nil value`.

Since you intended to use the `Object:Transform` function from your module, the easy fix is to rename the function argument to avoid the name collision. Try something like :

```
function spookyEngine:Transform(obj, pos, size, rotation)
    object:Transform(obj, pos, size, rotation)
end
```

Comment: Alright thanks! I will try that now!